# virtual environment in python3.4 won't import different modules

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv

as a little disclaimer I'm completely new to both Linux/Terminal and Python, so excuse the imprecise terminology

I'm trying to follow the basic usage guide for the python-based scientific calculator [PyPhi](https://github.com/wmayner/pyphi), a dedicated tool for calculated integrated information in a network. [I've followed the installation guide](https://github.com/wmayner/pyphi/blob/develop/INSTALLATION.md), in which I brew installed the latest versions of python and python3 (2.7.9 and 3.4.2 at the time of writing), pip installed virtualenvwrapper, changed the ~/.bash_profile as suggested to

```
## Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/dev
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

and also installed numpy for both 2.7.9 and 3.4.2. When I create a virtual environment using the command

```
mkvirtualenv -p `which python3` <name_of_your_project>
```

as suggested, I am able to `import pyphi`, but then attempting to `import numpy as np` brings up the error message

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

This doesn't happen when I run python3 without a virtual environment, as I can import both pyphi and numpy. What's gone wrong with the virtualenvironment setup so that it doesn't work whilst in there?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240653/how-to-install-a-package-inside-virtualenv-python), I think, you've got similar problem. There are two ways: quick&dirty and proper. Choose your own.

By the way, did you try adding Frameworks directory for 3.4.2 to `$PATH`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're right the problem was the same and actually very basic! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

PyPhi author here—it looks like you correctly created the virtual environment but didn't install the package while it was activated.

Make sure the virtual environment is active by running `workon <name_of_your_project` before running `pip install pyphi`.

Comment: I've updated the installation instructions to make this more explicit.