# How to use pip in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, windows, pip, virtualenv

I'm trying to install **Django** and I've created a virtual environment for this project (I'm new in virtualenv). I've created the env this way: `virtualenv path` which seems to work properly since there is a new folder "env" in my project folder.

Now I tried to install **Django** into this **virtualenv**.

```
\PycharmProjects\Django_tutorial>env/bin/pip install django
```

> 'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

So I've checked the **env** folder and there are these folders: `Include`, `Lib`, `Scripts`

In the `Scripts` folder, there is a`pip.exe` so I've decided to try it that way:

```
\PycharmProjects\Django_tutorial>env/Scripts/pip install django
```

The same thing occured:

> 'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Do you have any advices how to run this thing correctly?

EDIT: Python 2.7.10 and Windows 8.1

Comment: Could you add your windows version and python version please?

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro I've edited the question - Python 2.7.10 and Windows 8.1

Comment: See also [python - How to install a package inside virtualenv? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240653/how-to-install-a-package-inside-virtualenv) for how to use pip in virtual environment in general -- this particular question is is about backslashes in Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to activate a your virtual environment first;
Check this for how to activate virtual env,
https://virtualenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide.html

To install pip packages, you just need to call in terminal:

```
pip install package_name
```

This will directly install the package to your virtual env.

Answer (score 3):

Windows paths use backslashes, as shown in the prompt, not forwards ones.

```
env\Scripts\pip install django
```

although I don't know why you should need to use the full path at all; just `pip install django` should work once the venv is activated.