# Installing python package numpy on a particular version of python

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 versions of `Python` installed in my machine. Version numbers are `3.4` and `2.7.2`.

However, when I manage to `python --version` i get the following output, which is also the expected output:

```
Python 2.7.2
```

However, when I say `pip install numpy`. the package numpy gets installed in where I installed `python 3.4` :

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\python\lib\site-packages
```

How can I make `numpy` get installed in `Python 2.7.2` . The location where Python 2.7.2 is located is `C:\Python27`

Comment: Are you using anaconda or virtual environments?

Comment: I think its virtual env. How can I check this ? I am a newbie

Comment: what do you do when you want to use python 3.4 instead of 2.7?

Comment: I did this to change to python 2.7 `virtualenv venv --python=C:\Python27\python.exe` . So, its virtualenv that i use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a package inside virtualenv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240653/how-to-install-a-package-inside-virtualenv)