# how to pip install a package under conda virtual env

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, conda

I need to install mpl_finance under a conda virtual environment, this package is not available via conda, only pip can install. I have tried below, does not work out, please advice.

I first set up a virtual env called cs231p under `user/miniconda3/envs/cs231p`.
I cd to user/miniconda3/envs/cs231p/bin, and activated the env

```
conda activate cs231p
```

Then I do: conda list to make sure pip is there:

```
    ca-certificates           2019.1.23                     0  
    certifi                   2019.3.9                 py37_0  
    libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
    libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
    libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0  
    libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4  
    ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_1  
    openssl                   1.1.1b               h1de35cc_1  
    pip                       19.0.3                   py37_0
```

Then I do:

```
which pip
```

shows

```
 /miniconda3/envs/cs231p/bin/pip
```

`(cs231p) bin$ pip install mpl_finance`

I got error: but the path of pip is not from the virtual env that I set up.

> XXX/anaconda/bin/python3.5: can't open file 'install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

```
python -m pip install mpl_finance
```

gives

> requirement already satisfied:mpl_finance in
>   ~/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages (0.10.0)

Comment: instead of `pip install ...` you can also use `python -m pip install ....`

Comment: I'd be curious the know the output of `which pip` (in the activated env)

Comment: updated in my question @furas

Comment: updated in my question @cosmic_inquiry

Comment: always show full Traceback, not only last line. You run `pip install` and you get `python3.5 can't open file install` - it looks like your `pip` is not real `pip` but alias for `python3.5`. Run `python3.5 install mpl_finance` and you get the same error. Maybe you have own local script/file with name `pip` and when you run it then it uses this script instead of expected `pip`. You can always try full path `/miniconda3/envs/cs231p/bin/pip install mpl_finance`. You can also create new environment to test if it is only problem with this one environment.

Comment: @furas thanks it works! If you'd like to put your help into answer I will accept it.

Comment: Not sure if conda has any specific option, but there's [python - How to install a package inside virtualenv? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240653/how-to-install-a-package-inside-virtualenv) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `pip install ...` you can also use `python -m pip install ....`

But you run `pip install` and you get `python3.5 can't open file "install"` - it looks like your `pip` is not real `pip` but alias for `python3.5`.

Run `python3.5 install mpl_finance` and you get the same error.

Maybe you have own local script/file with name `pip` and when you run it then it uses this script instead of expected `pip`.

You can always try full path `/miniconda3/envs/cs231p/bin/pip install mpl_finance`.

You can also create new environment to test if it is only problem with this one environment.

Comment: how can i remove the mapping between "pip" command to python3.5 per your comments? i think this the trouble maker. Thx! @furas

Comment: I don't know - I never met this problem before. Firts you would have to find current `pip` - ie using `which pip` and remove it or rename it. And maybe later it will work correctly if it can find correct `pip` - or you would have to copy correct `pip` in place/folder where was wrong `pip` (or create soft link - something like `ln -s /path/to/correct/pip /path/to/previous/wrong/pip`

Answer (score 1):

1. activate anaconda virtual environment

   ```
   conda activate <env name>
   ```
2. install the package using pip

   ```
   python -m pip install <package>
   ```
3. deactivate conda virtual env

   ```
   conda deactivate
   ```

Comment: The original version of the answer was exactly the same steps that the OP followed. I retracted the vote after the edit.

Comment: I tried but it does not work out, Python -m seems install to anaconda's package instead of the virtual environment, please see details in my updated question.

Comment: @Lisa system python verson is same as virtual env ?