# How to correctly reinstall pip on macOS X to use venv? (EnviromentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied)

Tags: python, macos, pip, homebrew, sudo

I am completely new to Python, so in order to do some practice and whatnot decided to create a venv, when I found out those exist, and do it all there.

I'm on macOS X so I already have Python2 but obviously went to get 3.

I installed the latest Python version with its package from python.org itself. Tried to get pip and venv but wouldn't work. So, then I installed Homebrew and also run the code to install python3 as well because I read it would come with pip already among other things.

It didn't come with pip and it proved terribly difficult to install it. Also creating a venv has gotten me lost since I never coded in Python before.

I've gotten everything I've done in the Terminal

I installed the latest Python3.7.3 for Mac OS X from https://www.python.org/downloads/
I ran the package and it would also supposedly come with everything but when I ran

```
MacBook-Air:~ maria$ pip --version
-bash: pip: command not found
```

So I did what their guide to install pip said

```
MacBook-Air:~ maria$ python -m ensurepip --default-pip

Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
Collecting pip
Installing collected packages: pip
  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/folders/gj/g8j11snx2ll5xswmw_3696080000gn/T/tmpefPJJh/pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 246, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/var/folders/gj/g8j11snx2ll5xswmw_3696080000gn/T/tmpefPJJh/pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/commands/install.py", line 352, in run
      root=options.root_path,
    File "/var/folders/gj/g8j11snx2ll5xswmw_3696080000gn/T/tmpefPJJh/pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 693, in install
      **kwargs
    File "/var/folders/gj/g8j11snx2ll5xswmw_3696080000gn/T/tmpefPJJh/pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 817, in install
      self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
    File "/var/folders/gj/g8j11snx2ll5xswmw_3696080000gn/T/tmpefPJJh/pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1018, in move_wheel_files
      isolated=self.isolated,
    File "/var/folders/gj/g8j11snx2ll5xswmw_3696080000gn/T/tmpefPJJh/pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 237, in move_wheel_files
      clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
    File "/var/folders/gj/g8j11snx2ll5xswmw_3696080000gn/T/tmpefPJJh/pip-6.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 208, in clobber
      os.makedirs(destdir)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
      mkdir(name, mode)
  OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'
```

Then I did

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

with the result

```
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

Then I even installed command line developer tools from Xcode to have it all ready and make sure I'm not missing anything.
After this, I installed Homebrew and used it to install python3 and I noticed it said

```
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/2to3
Target /usr/local/bin/2to3
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/2to3'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite python

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run python

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/2to3 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/2to3
/usr/local/bin/2to3-3.7 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/2to3-3.7
/usr/local/bin/idle3 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/idle3
/usr/local/bin/idle3.7 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/idle3.7
/usr/local/bin/pydoc3 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pydoc3
/usr/local/bin/pydoc3.7 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pydoc3.7
/usr/local/bin/python3 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3-config -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3-config
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
/usr/local/bin/python3.7-config -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7-config
/usr/local/bin/python3.7m -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7m
/usr/local/bin/python3.7m-config -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7m-config
/usr/local/bin/pyvenv -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pyvenv
/usr/local/bin/pyvenv-3.7 -> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pyvenv-3.7
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/bin/python3 -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/bin/python3 -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/bin/python3 -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install
==> Caveats
Python has been installed as
  /usr/local/bin/python3
```

So after it, I still ran

```
MacBook-Air:~ maria$ pip --version
-bash: pip: command not found
MacBook-Air:~ maria$ python -m ensurepip --default-pip
```

With the result

```
 OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'
```

plus one last time

```
MacBook-Air:~ maria$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

but again got

```
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

So, ended up doing the deprecated `sudo easy_install pip`

```
MacBook-Air:~ maria$ pip --version
pip 19.0.3 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-19.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)
MacBook-Air:~ maria$ python3 -m ensurepip --default-pip
Looking in links: /var/folders/gj/g8j11snx2ll5xswmw_3696080000gn/T/tmpilb3zgrc
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (40.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (19.0.3)
```

against all my fears of messing something up but that worked, ironically. The problem is I can't do venvs because I get the `[Errno 13] Permission denied` and I'm not sure I want to keep on experimenting and mess it up for real.

Lastly did `pip install --user pipenv` which said to have be worked successfully with some notes.

```
Installing collected packages: virtualenv-clone, enum34, typing, certifi, virtualenv, setuptools, pipenv
  The script virtualenv-clone is installed in '/Users/maria/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The script virtualenv is installed in '/Users/maria/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  The scripts pipenv and pipenv-resolver are installed in '/Users/maria/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed certifi-2019.3.9 enum34-1.1.6 pipenv-2018.11.26 setuptools-41.0.0 typing-3.6.6 virtualenv-16.4.3 virtualenv-clone-0.5.3
```

And I'm not sure how to proceed from here. If I installed everything correctly, if I can start now or do I need to undo something, etc.
 I tried the most I could possibly do before nagging anyone. I'm willing to uninstall everything and do it again from 0.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of virtual environment:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html
To create a virtual environment, decide upon a directory where you want to place it, and run the venv module as a script with the directory path:
`python3 -m venv tutorial-env`
Then to activate the virtual environment:`source tutorial-env/bin/activate`
Activating the virtual environment will change your shell’s prompt to show what virtual environment you’re using, and modify the environment so that running python will get you that particular version and installation of Python.

Comment: Yes, I have done this before, it would start a venv suposedly succesfully. My question is if it is affecting child or parents in any form when it creates it. Like if I can install pandas globally or numpy or should I do it always inside some venv. Is there anything in my tortuous procedure that may create a problem affecting all Python globally.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240653/how-to-install-a-package-inside-virtualenv. Here you go.

Comment: Thanks but as pointed by a commenter, it defeats the venv purpose itself: In general, --system-site-packages should be avoided. This flag defeats the entire point of virtualenvs (which is why --no-site-packages was made the default a few versions ago).

Comment: Below,  there are answers for installing jnside  the virtual environment, you need to go to that direcotry and activate your source which is mentioned in my answer after that just use pip3 to install packages to that venv.