# can't import http scapy

Tags: python, http, scapy

so when i'm trying to import http for scapy in a python code like this

```
from scapy.layers.http import *
```

it returns this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scapy.layers.http'
```

but in the scapy terminal it works perfecty fine, i tried to look up the 
error on google but i can't find anything about it, all i find is peoples telling that you have to import http like this (from scapy.layers.http import *) but that doesn't work for me, any idea how i can fix that? or other ways i can filter http packets?

test code:

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.http import *


def ccc(pack):
    return HTTP in pack


a = sniff(lfilter=ccc, count=1)

a.show()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/name/Desktop/python tests/dontdeleteitit'stest.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scapy.layers.http import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scapy.layers.http'
```

Comment: Have you checked the environment

Comment: what do you mean? @Emad

Comment: I think you are using a virtual environment.Check this out:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240653/how-to-install-a-package-inside-virtualenv

Comment: i'm using pycharm

Comment: Have you installed it ? https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-scapy-v2-x

Comment: yea i did install scapy.

Comment: In that case please share your complete error output @Rebel.

Comment: @null_override i'm using windows and that post telling how to do it in linux

Comment: @Shakeel here i added the information in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using PyCharm(mentioned in comments) can you cross check your installed libraries ? 
you can use this shortcut on windows -> `ctlr + alt + s`

You should see scapy in the list if it is installed( please see below highlighted item).
[image]

if it is not installed then click on  `+` button search for `scapy` and install it directly.

If everything looks good then probably you need to configure you runner to point to correct interpreter where `scapy` is installed.

Comment: Oh, i realized i had an 2.4.0 version of scapy, this is why it didn't worked, now i updated it and it works, thank you so much :D